# Is there a basic layout that supports padding?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Is there a basic layout in the Spark classes that support padding? VerticalLayout and HorizontalLayout both support padding but BasicLayout does not.

Comment: I would think the answer is "trivially, no" -- as you alluded to, the documentation states "The BasicLayout class does not support padding properties because this layout requires that you explicitly position each child."  Could you show an example of how you want the layout to look?

Comment: @Brian they have a good point but you have padding in all HTML elements. it has its uses and like most layout features they are there for convenience. You could use the same arguments about the vertical and horizontal layouts, "... you don't need those layouts since you could explicitly position them vertically or horizontally" but they exist for convenience.

Comment: Could you show an example of a desired layout?  I'm not sure which of the available Spark classes qualify as "a basic layout".  e.g. TileLayout supports padding, but I wouldn't by any stretch call it a "basic layout".

Comment: By basic I mean poisoned absolutely or explicitly. I'm not sure what the correct term would be but it's explicitly positioning an element rather than having a layout class position the element(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No; the BasicLayout class does not support padding.**

As for the other layouts available in Flex:

- BasicLayout - no (only one child at a time)

  - StackLayout - no
- ButtonBarHorizontalLayout - is a horizontal layout
- LinkListHorizontalLayout - is a modification of ButtonBarHorizontalLayout
- ConstraintLayout - ?  No padding but constraints may serve
- FormItemLayout  - No
- HorizontalLayout - not a basic layout
- MosaicLayoutBase - ? (children must support padding)

  - FlowLayout - not basic (like a smart horizontal layout with overflow to row 2; works in columns, too)
  - SmartColumnLayout - not basic (multiple columns of different heights, new children added to shortest column)
  - SmartGridLayout - not basic (automatically adjusts proportions based on # of children and rows)
  - SmartRowLayout - not basic (multiple rows of different widths, new children added to shortest row)
- TabbedViewNavigatorTabBarHorizontalLayout - is a horizontal layout
- TileLayout - yes but not a basic layout
- ViewMenuLayout - no (is only for mobile viewmenu containers)
- VerticalLayout - not a basic layout

Comment: So it looks like I or someone might have to write one.